# How can I use iperf and grep both in a python script?

Tags: python, grep, subprocess, iperf

I tried many methods described but its not working with me. Can anybody please explain how can I use this in a single python script using the subprocess?

iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -i 1 -t 100 | grep -Po '[0-9.]*(?= Mbits/sec)'

Comment: Piping from one command to another is a shell feature, so you *must* specify `shell=True` on the subprocess method you use. But why not just iterate over the output in Python and forego the unnecessary `grep`?

Comment: What didn't work? How didn't it work?

Comment: bes = subprocess.Popen(["iperf", "-c", 10.0.1.1 | "grep","-Po", [0-9.]*(?= Mbits/sec)'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

Comment: This is how I am using it. Its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have resolved the problem. The idea is to use both the commands with different sub-processes. First create the process for `iperf` and input the out of this process to the `stdin` of the second process of the `grep` command as below:

```
process1 = subprocess.Popen(["iperf","-c", 10.10.0.1],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

prrocess2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-Po",[0-9.]*(?= Mbits/sec)], stdin=process1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```